# Excel VBA Select multiple sheet

Tags: vba

I'm trying to make a selection of multiple sheets one workbook based on run macros. At the end I have string containing sheets for selection, but my program prompt errors ...

Example:

```
SheetPrintPDF=Split(SheetPrintPDFTemp, ",")  
Rem Debug show me that SheetPrintPDFTemp contains "Sheet1, Sheet17, Sheet24"  

Wb1.Sheets(Array(SheetPrintPDF)).Select  
Rem Program error "method class sheet error"
```

when I write ...

```
Wb1.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet17", "Sheet24")).Select
```

Select works fine.

Comment: Could the whitespace after the comma be causing it? Try splitting on `", "`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't need to label the array as an array in your desired code because it already is one.  Try:

```
Wb1.Sheets(SheetPrintPDF).Select
```

Comment: This and Mat's Mug's comment together fixed it

Comment: Hi result is "Runtime error 9 : Subscript is out of range"

Answer (score 0):

I solved by filling the values directly into the field into the FOR loop

Example. **`ArrayTemp(x) = SheetPrintPDFTemp`**